# Android geocoder inaccurate, but only for MY package name

Tags: android, geocode

I have an app that is quite dependent on reverse geocoding results using the built-in Geocoding support in Android. However, I've been noticing that the geocoder object returns inaccurate results, which can be off several hundreds of meters/yards. The strangest thing however, is that this inaccuracy seems to be caused by my package name!

If I run the sample code that you can download at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html everything works like a charm. The reverse geocoder almost always gets the right street number, and in some cases my neighbor's street number.

However, if I take the same sample code, and ONLY change the package name into my app's package name, suddenly the reverse geocoding is very inaccurate. Also, the latitude and longitude that the geocoder service returns are very different from the ones that I provided the geocoder with.

As far as I can tell, the Android geocoder is NOT subject to any usage limits. But how can I get inaccurate results just based on the package name? That's really frustrating for both me and my users (over half a million).

Comment: About the usage limits, yes, they exist. http://developer.android.com/legal.html . When using geocode you are bound to Google Maps Terms. Besides the limits, you legally can't use the Geocode if you don't show the geocode result on a Google Map. Item 10.1.1-g) here: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Comment: The fact that I need to display the result a map isn't an issue for my app. The legal notice doesn't mention any limits to the number of geocoding requests that you do. If I'm wrong, please guide me towards a source that specifically mentions the usage/quota limits.

Comment: From the Geocoding API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits): "Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day". There's a "Google Maps API for Business" with higher limits that can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing (i don't know about the cost tho).